# Is the set linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

> Is the set of vectors linearly dependent? If so write one of them as a combination of others.

**Answer:** By the zero vector theorem, since the set contains the zero vectors, it must be that the set is **linearly dependent.**

**Find one vector as a combination of others.**

I am unable to do that, but it should work?

I am still getting all coefficients to be $0$?

Comment: It's still a linear combination if the coefficients are zero.

Comment: @juanarroyo, but that would make it linearly independent

Comment: The relation you have is $0\times \vec {v_1}+0\times \vec {v_2}=1\times \vec {v_3}$.  Sure, two of the coefficients are $0$ but not all three.

Comment: Vectors ${v_i}$ are linearly independent if $\sum c_i v_i=0 \implies$ all the coefficients are zero. That condition is false for these vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-3\\
-2
\end{pmatrix} +0
\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
4\\
6\\
1
\end{pmatrix}+k
\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$

The equation holds for any $k \ne 0$. Then the set of vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Amad27: is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

Any set of vectors containing the zero vector is linearly dependent.

The zero vector, $0$, can be shown to be a linear combination of any other vectors with coefficients all 0, except $a$ can be an arbitrary number and this criteria is met, so the zero vector being in a set of vectors causes them to become a linearly dependent set. There then exists a dependence relation.

Recall, a finite set {$x_i $} of vectors is linearly dependent if there exists a corresponding set {$a_i $} of scalars, not all zero, such that $\sum_i a_ix_i = 0$.